# Catching exceptions out of 'stream()' or 'parallelStream()' loses correct values

Tags: java, exception, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

In the following code, when catching `NumberFormatException` out of `for` iteration, the strings in appropriate form appearing in `strList` before the first bad one (i.e., `"illegal_3"`) have been parsed successfully (i.e., `"1"` and `"2"` have been parsed as integers `1` and `2`).

```
public void testCaughtRuntimeExceptionOutOfIteration() {
    List<String> strList = Stream.of("1", "2", "illegal_3", "4", "illegal_5", "6").collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        for (String str : strList) {
            intList.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }

    List<Integer> expectedIntList = Stream.of(1, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // passed
    assertEquals("The first two elements have been parsed successfully.", expectedIntList, intList);  
}
```

However, when replacing `for` iteration by `stream()` or `parallelStream()`, I lose `1` and `2`.

```
public void testCaughtRuntimeExceptionOutOfStream() {
    List<String> strList = Stream.of("1", "2", "illegal_3", "4", "illegal_5", "6").collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        intList = strList.stream()  // same with "parallelStream()"
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }

    List<Integer> expectedIntList = Stream.of(1, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // failed: expected:<[1,2]>, but was:<[]>
    assertEquals("The first two elements have been parsed successfully.", expectedIntList, intList);  
}
```

> What is the specification of the control flow of exceptions thrown from within `stream()` or `parallelStream()`?
>
> How can I get the result of `intList = [1,2]` (i.e., ignore the ones after the first `NumberFormatException` is thrown) or even better `intList = [1,2,4,6]` (i.e., ignore the bad ones with `NumberFormatException`) with `stream()` or `parallelStream()`

Comment: I just was thinking about same things yesterday. +1 for good question

Comment: There are many related questions (too many to list them here, and some of them might (at least nearly) be duplicates). The short form: The control flow specification is always the same, regardless of whether you're using streams or not. If you don't want the exceptions to bubble out and interrupt the control flow, you'll have to catch them locally. BTW: Note that even **if** you worked around the exception itself: IIRC, the result with a `parallelStream` might still be `[2,1]`....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just wrap lambda-body in `try...catch`?

Also you can filter `null` values after `map`:

```
    intList = strList.stream()// same with "parallelStream()"
            .map(x -> {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(x);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            })
            .filter(x -> x!= null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will give you desired `intList = [1,2,4,6]`.

Edit: To reduce the "heaviness" of a try/catch in a lamdba you can add a helper method.

```
static Integer parseIntOrNull(String s) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

intList = strList.stream()
            .map(x -> parseIntOrNull(x))
            .filter(x -> x!= null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or to avoid using null, you can return a Stream

```
static Stream<Integer> parseIntStream(String s) {
    try {
        return Stream.of(Integer.parseInt(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }
    return Stream.empty();
}

intList = strList.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> parseIntStream(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, it works.  Thanks. (However, I think the `try ... catch` block is too *heavy* to be in `lambda-body`.)

Comment: @hengxin too heavy? why? It doesn't make it heavy in any way. It is wrong assumption...

Comment: "Heavy" syntactically; nothing else. It is a good work-around.

Comment: @Andremoniy My apologies for the long edit. I though it would be shorter when I started.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is a honour for me to have such cooperative answer with you :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Optional` is another option for avoiding `null`.

Answer (score 2):

A method can't both return a value, and throw an exception. That is impossible.

So you can't expect `collect()` to both return a list, and throw an exception. Since if throws an exception, it can't return a new list.

If your for loop code was actually similar to the stream code, you would have the same problem:

```
public void testCaughtRuntimeExceptionOutOfIteration() {
    List<String> strList = Stream.of("1", "2", "illegal_3", "4", "illegal_5", "6").collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        intList = collectToIntegers(strList);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }

    List<Integer> expectedIntList = Stream.of(1, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // fails
    assertEquals("The first two elements have been parsed successfully.", expectedIntList, intList);  
}

private List<Integer> collectToIntegers(List<String> strList) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : strList) {
       result.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
    return result;
}
```

In short: don't confuse "creating and returning a new list", with "taking a list and add elements to it".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many times I encountered a situation where I just wanted to ignore the NumberFormatException. I would probably create a separate re-usable method to parse integer silently and return OptionalInt value.

Here is the utils class

```
public class IntUtils {
    // ... other utility methods

    public static OptionalInt parseInt(String s, Consumer<? super Exception> exceptionConsumer) {
        try {
            return OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (exceptionConsumer != null) {
                // let the caller take the decision
                exceptionConsumer.accept(e);
            } else {
                // default behavior
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return OptionalInt.empty();
    }

    public static OptionalInt parseInt(String s) {
        return parseInt(s, null);
    }
}
```

Here is the test method

```
List<Integer> collect1 = strStream.map(str -> IntUtils.parseInt(str, Exception::printStackTrace))
            .filter(OptionalInt::isPresent)
            .map(OptionalInt::getAsInt).collect(toList());

// or 
List<Integer> collect2 = strStream.map(IntUtils::parseInt)
            .filter(OptionalInt::isPresent)
            .map(OptionalInt::getAsInt).collect(toList());
```

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

I am using `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`:

```
.mapToInt(s -> NumberUtils.toInt(s, Integer.MIN_VALUE))
.filter(x -> x > Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```