# Specification of exceptions and parallelStream

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of parallelStream when (unchecked) exceptions arise. I'm confused about the following code, when changing
between `stream()` and `parallelStream()` adds (sometimes) a cause to my exception.
This is the code: if you run it many times, often you get just
`RuntimeException`, but sometimes you get
`RuntimeException` caused by `RuntimeException`.
If I change with any other kind of Exception, I still get the same effect:
`Bla`, but sometimes you get
`Bla` caused by `Bla`.

```
List<Integer> nums=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {nums.add(i);}
List<Integer> res=nums.parallelStream().filter(n->{
  if(n %13==0) {throw new RuntimeException(""+n);}
  return true;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is loosely connected with 
[Catching exceptions out of 'stream()' or 'parallelStream()' loses correct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564025/catching-exceptions-out-of-stream-or-parallelstream-loses-correct-values)
But no answer in that question seams to address this point.
I also looked to 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html
but that did not mention this issue at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A Throwable in java have method getCause() and
It can either be getCause()==null, or getCause()==anotherThrowable.
In my code, sometimes I get null, sometimes I get (exactly) 2 chained exceptions

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Indeed streams inside use the FJ job stealing, it was hard to think about that and find the connection for me!